# Error with Insert SQL commands

Tags: mysql, sql

```
insert into DOG
(DogName,DogBreed,DogDOB,DogWeight,Fixed)
Values
('Lasie', 'Sheppard', '1/1/11', '80lbs','1');
```

Error:Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I'm not sure if this error relates to Date (DogDOB), or Fixed which was defined as 1

Comment: Well, what are the column types in the `DOG` table?

Comment: is FIXED field bit, integer or varchar?

Comment: Data Type is "bit"

Comment: Please include the DDL you used. We cannot help you without knowing what your table looks like. You will also most likely get faster and better answers when you provide a working sqlfiddle.

Comment: I apologize I was given an erd with what was set for me to create my table: 

DogID:   INT  NOT NULL 
DogName: CHAR(20)  NOT NULL
DogBreed: CHAR(20)  NOT NULL
DogDOB:  DATE   NOT NULL
DogWeight:  Decimal(3,2)
Fixed:  BIT  NOT NULL

This is what I was given in my ERD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment about your table structure being:

```
CREATE TABLE Dog (
    DogID INT NOT NULL,
    DogName CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DogBreed CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DogDOB DATE NOT NULL,
    DogWeight Decimal(3,2),
    Fixed BIT NOT NULL
)
```

Your problem is the 80lbs because it has the 'lbs' in it and is expecting only a numeric value.

```
insert into DOG
(DogName,DogBreed,DogDOB,DogWeight,Fixed)
Values ('Lasie', 'Sheppard', '1/1/11', 80,1);
```

One additional issue though is `80` is too large for `decimal(3,2)` which only supports `9.99`.  So you would have to use `decimal(4,2)` in that case.

Comment: @jh86 you have one additional issue though is 80 is out of range for decimal(3,2)  that data type would only support 9.99

Comment: @Marvin nope, hadn't but I did just notice the decimal issue and have updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your query:

- The `DogID` column doesn't have a default value, so you have to either define it as `auto_increment` or provide one.
- `DogWeight` is defined as `DECIMAL(3, 2)` so you cannot provide a string. It is also defined to have at most one digit before the decimal point, so `80` would be already out of range. You can provide values up to `9.99`.
- `Fixed` is defined as `BIT` so you can only provide numeric values up to `64`.
- The `DogDOB` column is defined as `DATE` which expects values in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. While this will not result in an error, `1/1/11` will most certainly not do what you expect to get.

A working query could look like this:

```
insert into DOG
  (DogID, DogName, DogBreed, DogDOB, DogWeight, Fixed)
values
  (1, 'Lasie', 'Sheppard', '2011/1/1', 8.21, 1);
```

See this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f2fcb).

Comment: upvote for more complete and finding the additional issues beyond the original error message